# GET request returns different JSON contents

Tags: get, scrapy

I am crawling some data by using Scrapy. Every time I open [product detail](https://shopee.vn/H%E1%BB%99p-%C4%91%E1%BB%B1ng-gi%C3%A0y-trong-su%E1%BB%91t-theo-d%C3%B5i-c%C3%B3-gi%C3%A1-t%E1%BB%91t-i.6088300.43369300) on browser and check [this request](https://shopee.vn/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=43369300&shop_id=6088300) was requested by browser always returned the same correct content without character '?????'
But if I open the request above on browser then It returned correct content about 10 times. Then, It returned wrong content by adding character '?????'
Can you explain why does this problem happen? And how to make Scrapy act as real browser?
This is correct content

```
{"itemid": 43369300, "liked": false, "offer_count": 6, "videos": [], "image": "41dabd8fe9b7cbc2ab30501592f65a80", "image_list": ["41dabd8fe9b7cbc2ab30501592f65a80", "91bf75885fffd2b1fbcc55099457bc22", "f4516bb9667f8329f031ff75896a71fd", "d2639a1ffe75912873de6d8e011dc0dd", "38d00637b021e1701542a6afa7ae58f3", "10ab99e3bd211bd4dd63993555d6454b"].....
```

And this is wrong content

```
{"itemid": 43369300, "liked": false, "offer_count": 10, "videos": [], "rating_star": 4.069458216402549, "image": "41dabd8fe9?????????????????????", "image_list": ["41dabd8fe9?????????????????????", "91bf75885f?????????????????????", "f4516bb966?????????????????????", "d2639a1ffe?????????????????????", "38d00637b0?????????????????????", "10ab99e3bd?????????????????????"].....
```

You can test with other requests [request1](https://shopee.vn/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=63785137&shop_id=6088300), [request2](https://shopee.vn/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=91774823&shop_id=6088300),...

Comment: List the url on which you get "????" and is it that it happens on the same URL when you it again and again? Also post the content in a pastebin and post the link

Comment: I edited my question as your comment @TarunLalwani

Comment: I checked and refreshing in browser 5-10 times, the content for same request changes. This is obviously scraping protection in action. You need to use proxies and rotate your requests

Comment: why do I open product pages on browser then firebug show responses without character '?????' Event I cleared cache and refresh more than 10 times

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you are hitting the API directly and they are preventing scraping. If I hit the below URL using curl and extra headers 10-15 times, it works fine

```
curl 'https://xxxx.vn/api/v0/shop/6088300/item/43369300/shipping_info_to_address/?state=H%C3%A0%20N%E1%BB%99i&city=Huy%E1%BB%87n%20Ba%20V%C3%AC&district=' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
-H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'X-API-SOURCE: pc' \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'  \
-H 'Referer: https://xxx.vn/H%E1%BB%99p-%C4%91%E1%BB%B1ng-gi%C3%A0y-trong-su%E1%BB%91t-theo-d%C3%B5i-c%C3%B3-gi%C3%A1-t%E1%BB%91t-i.6088300.43369300' \
--compressed
```

So I think 4 important headers that you should send are below

```
'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
'X-API-SOURCE: pc'
'Referer: https://xxx.vn/H%E1%BB%99p-%C4%91%E1%BB%B1ng-gi%C3%A0y-trong-su%E1%BB%91t-theo-d%C3%B5i-c%C3%B3-gi%C3%A1-t%E1%BB%91t-i.6088300.43369300'
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
```

Send these headers while creating the Request in Scrapy

Comment: It still returns characters "??????" @Tarun I tested your request with Postman chrome app

Comment: in Scrapy or in curl? How are you testing?

Comment: I removed CSRF and cookies to see if it works, but i guess you might need cookies also. See what you need is to make sure you get it as close to the browser as possible

Comment: I test with extract headers (I copied from Chrome) but not work :(

Comment: In your Chrome network tab, use Copy as curl on the API call and see if it works using curl, if it does then you are doing something wrong in Postman

Comment: please check your answer, my question about https://shopee.vn/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=43369300&shop_id=6088300, not about https://shopee.vn/api/v0/shop/6088300/item/43369300/shipping_info_to_address......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151875/discussion-between-huy-logarit-and-tarun-lalwani).